# Allow Traffice between two VPN AnyConnect users (Ping, RDP, etc..)

Tags: vpn, nat, cisco-anyconnect

How I can establish a connection between VPN clients? 
I would need someone to explain this by example. 
I could not see any clear reference to this subject

Comment: That is far too broad a question with many rat holes that will stop all traffic.  What do you know? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you using Cisco ASA or the ocserv server?

Comment: Yes I a musing ASA 5515.

Comment: I created the outside,outside nat and the access-list I also enabled the same interface traffic